# limited number of texts in textview

Tags: java, android, textview, line

First of all look at the image [image: the picture]

I want to the text near the "Google" image fill the empty area under the google image, look the area under the google image (in above pic) is empty and text arent filling up there.

how can i do that?

XML FILE :::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/allbg">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/newstop" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">




<!-- Name Label -->
    <!-- Input Name -->
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/slidebg"
android:id="@+id/slidebg"
android:layout_margin="7dp">

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/imgad2"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>










    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"   android:layout_below="@+id/slidebg"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01"    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"  android:layout_weight="1" >
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/btnshare"
android:background="@drawable/opbg"
android:text="Share"
android:paddingLeft="20dp"
android:paddingTop="4dp"
android:textSize="19dp"
android:textColor="#cccccc"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btncopy"
                android:background="@drawable/opbg"
                android:text="Copy"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:textSize="19dp"
                android:textColor="#cccccc"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow></TableLayout>




<!-- Price Label -->
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!-- Button Create Product -->
        <Button android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save Changes"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <!-- Button Create Product -->
        <Button android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Price"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:visibility="gone" />





<!-- Input Price -->
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputPrice"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<!-- Description Label -->

<!-- Input description -->





    <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/listrowbg"
    android:id="@+id/card_view4"

    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TableLayout01">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/titcon">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="#fafafa"
        android:textDirection="ltr"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    android:maxWidth="200dp"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:phoneNumber="false"
        android:text="Abadi - SohMj"
        android:layout_marginTop="-4dp" />




    <ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/newshead"
android:id="@+id/titsp"

        />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/titcon">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="این متن خبر تست است!"
        android:id="@+id/tvdes"
        android:maxLines="90"


    android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="18dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:textColor="#fcf8f8f8"
        android:layout_weight="0.95"
        android:maxLength="20000"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:weightSum="1"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:gravity="left|top"

    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:clickable="false">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image"
 />
</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="تمامی اخبار و نوشته ها حق رپفارسی می باشد و هرگونه کپی پیگرد دارد."
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/card_view4"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>



  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show xml file please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this library for wrapping your text around image..

https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView

Comment: hi, im facing problem with importing this project; can please instruct me?

Comment: it's working fine , i used it... i am using intellij 14.1.4....  Show me the error , what kind of problem you are facing... and also which build type you are using (eclipse, intellij, android studio)..

Answer (score 0):

Give the number in the attribute in xml

```
android:maxLength="100"
```

Comment: you guys code are just setting a max length for text view , i tried codes but the lines are still having empty places like picture...

Comment: You want to fill up the space under google image? Then why did you ask about limiting the numbers? Changes needs to be done in layout hierarchy.

Comment: Whats the resource id of the google image? Its not clear in the code.

Comment: the image view inside linearLayout2 ; please help me

Comment: the image view inside linearLayout2 ; please help me  @Anitha Manikandan

Comment: Do not create layout for each and every view.  Please organize it in relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting a Max Limit to your TextView

```
...
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" //your ImageView Height
    android:maxLines="1" //Number of Lines you need to limit
    android:maxLength="10" //character limit
    android:ellipsize="end"
..
```

..

Comment: you guys code are just setting a max length for text view , i tried codes but the lines are still having empty places like picture...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
   android:maxLength="12"
```

Comment: you guys code are just setting a max length for text view , i tried codes but the lines are still having empty places like picture...

Comment: can't understand what do you mean to me. Please tell me in detail

Comment: under the google picture there is no text! i want to my text fill the empty places under the google image

Comment: You need like this, http://help.midcompweb.com/webframe_guide/editing_web_pages/adding_a_picture_to_a_word_document/index.asp

Comment: i get this error "You are not authorized to view this page" and i think it isnt about android